# How to know if WM_GETMINMAXINFO is triggered by SIZE_RESTORED?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I'm implementing window constraints for my game and I have ran into a small issue.

I use this code to set the constraints:

```
case WM_GETMINMAXINFO:
     {
        LPMINMAXINFO p_info = (LPMINMAXINFO)lParam;
        RECT wRect;
        RECT cRect;
        int wWidth;
        int wHeight;
        int cWidth;
        int cHeight;
        int total_border_width;
        int total_border_height;
        POINT wmin, wmax;

        GetWindowRect(hWnd, &wRect);
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &cRect);
        wWidth = wRect.right - wRect.left;
        wHeight = wRect.bottom - wRect.top;
        cWidth = cRect.right - cRect.left;
        cHeight = cRect.bottom - cRect.top;
        total_border_width = wWidth - cWidth;
        total_border_height = wHeight - cHeight;

            wmin.x = (d->min_w > 0) ? d->min_w + (resize_is_restore ? -total_border_width : total_border_width) : p_info->ptMinTrackSize.x;
        wmin.y = (d->min_h > 0) ? d->min_h + total_border_height : p_info->ptMinTrackSize.y;
        wmax.x = (d->max_w > 0) ? d->max_w + total_border_width : p_info->ptMaxTrackSize.x;
        wmax.y = (d->max_h > 0) ? d->max_h + total_border_height : p_info->ptMaxTrackSize.y;

        p_info->ptMinTrackSize = wmin;
        p_info->ptMaxTrackSize = wmax;

            resize_is_restore = false;
     }
     break;
```

The problem was that the min_w constraint is not being respected when the window is restored.

I figured out I need to negate the total width in this situation:

```
wmin.x = (d->min_w > 0) ? d->min_w + (resize_is_restore ? -total_border_width : total_border_width) : p_info->ptMinTrackSize.x;
```

Unfortunatly, I cannot set resize_is_restore because the WM_SIZE message is sent after the WM_GETMINMAXINFO. Is there a way to find out that the resize is due to a restore before setting the minmaxinfo?

Thanks

Fixed it with:

```
    /* Fix for when the window is restored */
    if (cWidth == 0 && cHeight == 0) {
        break;
       }
```

Comment: Possibly you can see with Spy++ or a similar tool what messages are sent to your window when it is restored.

Comment: Your suggested change makes no sense to me. Sure, the problem is that the calculation is wrong, but you seem to be making it even more wrong in the hopes that the errors will even out and the result will be what you expect. Or can you explain why the negation is correct? Anyway, I'm not sure what's going wrong, but my first thought would be to avoid calculating total_border_{width,height} using a minimised window's size. You can use `GetSystemMetrics` instead.

Comment: GetSystemMetrics is no good because the window can be a variety of frames (thick border, thin border, no border, etc).

Comment: Are your constraints (`d->min_w`, etc.) fixed or do they vary?  With simple fixed constraints (say 200x200) this seems to work fine.

Comment: And do you change the window border dynamically or is it fixed for the duration of a window's life?